# how to upload folder in artifacts GCP storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to upload folder in artifacts:

My code in cloudbuild.yaml:

```
artifacts:
  objects:   
    location: 'REDACTED'
    paths: ['REDACTED']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/store-build-artifacts#store-artifact-storage):

Define your *YAML* build configuration file.

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: [STORAGE_LOCATION]
    paths: [[ARTIFACT_PATH],[ARTIFACT_PATH], ...]
```

Where,

- `[STORAGE_LOCATION]`: A Cloud Storage bucket or a folder within the bucket where Cloud Build must store the artifact, such as gs://mybucket or gs://mybucket/some/folder.
- `[ARTIFACT_PATH]`: Path to one or more artifacts.

Then, you will need to replace the values in brackets `[]` with the appropriate values. See example for [uploading files and folders](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/store-build-artifacts#uploading_files_and_folders).

Once your build completes successfully, you can find the upload results in the JSON manifest file located at `[STORAGE_LOCATION]`/artifacts-$BUILD_ID.json`.

---

*Edited*

As of today, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/store-build-artifacts#store-artifact-storage) points out the following:

1. You can specify only one bucket to upload the artifacts and you must be the owner of the bucket.
2. You can specify a valid directory path in the bucket.
3. You can upload any number of artifacts, but you can specify only up to one hundred artifact paths.

There is already a feature request created for specifying multiple bucket locations that you can follow via [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/153681781).

Comment: My location would be different like: I need two folder under one folder in bucket

gs://mob-pk-dev.appspot.com/Image/Profile_image/1.jpg
gs://mob-pk-dev.appspot.com/Image/data_image/2.png

Comment: You can specify up to 100 artifact paths, but specifying multiple bucket locations (buckets or folders within the bucket) is not supported. See my answer for further details.